# Does .NET Core Blazor web apps go to sleep like ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Does Core .NET Server Side web applications idle out after a while and need to wake back up like asp.net webforms do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on the server hosting it and is not inherent to ASP.NET Blazor itself.

As a general statement, you could turn this behavior on or off. (You can with IIS or Azure)

Answer (score 3):

With Azure you can turn on "Always On" and the Blazor app will *not* "go to sleep"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-general-settings

Comment: Yes, but not on the F1 (free) tier.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor server-side run on a server, so if you run it in IIS and your IIS server is configured to go idle after an inactivity periode then yes, as any web site on IIS it need a new request to wake up.

But an Asp.Net core web site can run on kestrel too which doesn't have idle conf